# jQuery load more wordpress posts with a loop that has two different formats

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm loading paged posts with a loop that has two different formats. I use a counter to determine if the post is the first post. If it is then it is formatted this way, if else (not first post) then format it another way.

I'm using js to load in paged posts when user scrolls to the bottom and it all works, however, it loads the paged post with the first post in format A. **I need it to load all paged posts but make them in format B**. How can I do this?

*My php wordpress loop to load posts:*

```
<?php
  // set up or arguments for our custom query
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged
  );
  // create a new instance of WP_Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $counter = 1; while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); if( $counter == 1 ) { ?>
    <article id ="featured">
        Format A
    </article>
<?php } else {?>
    <article id="non-featured">
        Format B
    </article>

<?php }
$counter++;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

*My JS:*

```
jQuery(function(){
var page = 2;
var myurl = 'http://MyURL.com/'
var loadmore = 'on';
jQuery(document).on('scroll resize', function() {
  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 200 > jQuery(document).height()) {
    if (loadmore == 'on') {
      loadmore = 'off';
      jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
      jQuery('#lazyload').append(jQuery('<div class="blog-grid" id="p' + page + '">').load(myurl + '/blog/page/' + page + ' article', function() {
        page++;
        loadmore = 'on';
        jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      }));
    }
  }
});
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, options ) {
    if ( $(".blog-grid").is(':empty'))
    {
       loadmore = 'off';
    }
  if (xhr.responseText.indexOf('class="blog-grid"') == -1) {
  }
});
});
```